# What is the TAK function for?

Tags: algorithms, recursion

We covered this in class today. I understand the mechanics of it, but aside from being a nice example of recursion does it serve any purpose?

[image]

Searching the web reveals lots of pages with the formula and it's implementation in code, some talk about the author, but nothing about it's purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use it to **evaluate the performance of programming languages**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tak_%28function%29

since recursive methods are pretty useful for benchmarking. In particular, deep recursion tests the speed with which a language can make method calls. This is important because modern applications have a tendency to spend much of their time calling various API functions.

You will also need it to **solve ballot problems** like this one:

```
Suppose A and B are candidates for office and there are 2n voters, n
voting for A and n for B. In how many ways can the ballots be counted
so that B is never ahead of A?
```

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallotProblem.html

or just to **generate Takeuchi Numbers**:

```
0, 1, 4, 14, 53, 223, 1034, 5221, 28437, ...
```

Comment: Although those links are unlikely to break, would you [quote the most relevant part of those links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)?